# Regex to filter for no-space string only

Tags: php, regex

I currently have the following regex:

```
(?<=\[)([^\]]+)
```

Result are as follows:

```
text* your-name
email* your-email
text your-subject
textarea your-message
submit "Submit"
your-subject
your-name
your-email
your-message
```

I'd like to adjust my regex so it filters out the results that have a space in between, so that I'm only left with following results:

```
your-subject
your-name
your-email
your-message
```

How can I do this?
Here's how it currently is: https://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/58

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/59

Comment: @splash58 Perfect, thanks. Could you explain what you have changed?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/60

Comment: I have just added space in the excluding group and the closing bracket

Comment: Maybe `\[\H+\]` is simplest?

Comment: ^ if it is not a single string

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?<=\[)[^]\s]+(?=])
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/rz9NG5/1) and [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/IX9tH). Note that the `$matches` structure is cleaner without a capturing group in the pattern, with all context checked using [non-consuming lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

**Details**

- `(?<=\[)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `[` immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^]\s]+`  - 1+ chars other than `]` (no need to escape it as it is the first char in the negated character class) and whitespace
- `(?=])` - a positive lookahead that requires a `]` immediately to the right of the current location (`]` is not special outside of a character class).

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/IX9tH):

```
$arr = ['[text* your-name]','[email* your-email]','[text your-subject]','[textarea your-message]','[submit "Verzenden"]','[your-subject]','[your-name]','[your-email]','[your-message]'];

foreach ($arr as $s) {
  if (preg_match_all('~(?<=\[)[^]\s]+(?=])~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => your-subject
)
Array
(
    [0] => your-name
)
Array
(
    [0] => your-email
)
Array
(
    [0] => your-message
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\[\K([^ \]]+)(?=\])/gm
```

Test this regex pattern at https://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/62

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your current pattern, all you have to do is to exclude the space or all the blank characters from your character class and to check there's a closing square bracket after. So `(?<=\[)([^]\s]+)(?=])` with the result in the whole match or in the capture group (that makes it useless).

But you can write a better pattern, more simple and more efficient: `\[([^]\s]+)]`. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ya4ge/1)

More simple because since there's a capture group, you don't have to use lookarounds to extract the content you want without the brackets. It's also shorter and easier to understand.

More efficient because of two start-up optimizations:

- The first and most important: when the pattern starts with a literal string (the opening bracket here), a fast algorithm searches the string for all positions where this literal string occurs in the subject string, and the pattern will be only tested at these positions. Otherwise, and this is the case if you enclose this bracket in a lookbehind, this start-up optimization isn't possible and the pattern will be tested at each position in the subject string.
- The second is called *auto-possessification*. It automatically makes a quantifier [possessive](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) at compile-time when eventual backtracks don't change the result. For instance, `a*b` becomes `a*+b` when `a.*b` stays `a.*b`. In our case, since the character class `[^]\s]` excludes the closing bracket, `[^]\s]+]` becomes `[^]\s]++]`. Concretely, when a space is found instead of the closing bracket, the greedy quantifier doesn't give characters back to try other possibilities, the pattern fails, and the regex engine tries the pattern at the next position. One more time, putting the bracket in a lookahead disables this optimization.

But why lookarounds disable these optimizations? The reason is simple, these optimizations require to study the pattern, so to keep these analyses fast, they are limited to simple cases. (Note that the capture group doesn't disturb the auto-possessification.)

---

If you absolutely want to avoid the capture group but want to keep these two optimizations, nothing forbids to write:

`\[\K[^]\s]++(?=])`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WsWUWm/1)

or more fun:

`\[(?=[^]\s]++\K])`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KyiUzq/1)

The two patterns start with a literal `[` and the possessive quantifier is added by hand.